# Resolver error "Primary script unknown" con Nginx

Tags: php, nginx

Al configurar en ubuntu 16.04 un LEMP (Nginx, MySQL, FPM) la versión 7 de PHP y FPM y cuando he ido a hacer una prueba con php, el log de nginx me tira esto.

> 2016/08/08 22:54:50 [error] 2251#2251: *4 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: fanut.localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "fanut.localhost"

Os dejo la configuración de mi virtual Host porque he leido que es del script de fastcgi pero no encuentro qué es lo que le pasa. Gracias de antemano.

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;

root /home/user/html/proyecto/public;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name proyecto.localhost www.proyecto.localhost;

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    #       # With php7.0-fpm:
    #       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }


# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo la configuración que me funciona en mi local y servers:

```
location ~ \.php($|/) {
    include fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock;

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS off;

    # fastcgi_index  local_index.php;
}
```

con `fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;` le indicas como debe dividirse la ruta que está utilizándose.

y con `fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;` le pasas el parámetro a `php-fpm`

Comment: Como detalle: no me conecto a php-fpm mediante un server, sino que mediante un socket file, por ello mi `fastcgi_pass` es diferente al tuyo.

Comment: nada, en el navegador me sigue saliendo "File Not Found"

Comment: que versión de nginx tienes? si haces un `$ ls /home/user/html/proyecto/public` está el archivo index.php o algún otro php?

Comment: pues tengo la versión 1.4.6 y sí, hay un par de ficheros, index.html y register.php. El fallo viene cuando intento acceder al register.php.

Comment: en servers agrega esto: `log_format scripts '$document_root$fastcgi_script_name > $request';` y `access_log /var/log/nginx/scripts.log scripts` , esto logueará el valor de las variables que están llegando a php-fpm y asi sabrás el valor de `SCRIPT_FILENAME`

Comment: y otra cosa, deja esta línea `include fastcgi_params;` como la primera del `location ~ \.php$`. Esta línea sobreescribe algunos valores, por ello debe ir al principio